# Mysql query to get data from 2 tables and display sub categories under main category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having some problem in retrieving sub categories from mysql database.I want to display the sub-categeories for the parent categories

The parent categories are stored in `Menu` table and sub_categories in `ITEM` table.

`Menu` table has columns `menu_id`,`Menu_name` and `restaurant_id`

`Item` table has columns `item_id`, `item_name` and `menu_id` (FK refrences `menu_id` of `menu`)

```
   $sqlmenu = "SELECT * FROM item t1 LEFT JOIN menu t2 ON t1.menu_id = t2.menu_id WHERE t2.restaurant_id = ?"; 
   $datamenu = DB::prepare($sqlmenu)->execute([$restaurant_id])->fetchAll();

    <?php foreach($datamenu as $rowmenu){ ?>
                    <ul>
                        <li><?php echo $rowmenu['menu_name']; ?></li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <?php echo $rowmenu['item_name']; ?>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
```

With above code, i am getting output like

```
    Main Category1
     -- Sub category1


    Main Category1
     -- Sub category2


    Main Category2
     -- Sub category1


    Main Category2
     -- Sub category2
```

Please help me out here. I know i including main category also in for loop but i want to do it with one query only not with multiple queries.

Comment: only suggestion I can make is `ORDER BY` the menu name and do a check to see if it has changed, if so start a new parent UL, otherwise use 2 queries.

Comment: @Bryan, My problem is that i have multiple enteries for item_name in sub category for its main category. FOr e.g. if menu has main category as "Starters" then item table has 2 types of startersand i need to display Main category once and two sub categories under that

Comment: Ill, show you what I mean. Gimme a minute.

Comment: `order by` query just sorted results in ASC Order.. which is true but not desirable

Comment: yeah, then check on each loop if it's the same as the last to decide when to start a new list. But the answer someone just posted is probably a better way than I was in the middle of showing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to accomplish this to use group_concat() the item_name in the query group by menu_name and then in the loop explode and generate the menu as

```
$sqlmenu = "SELECT 
t2.menu_id,t2.menu_name,group_concat(t1.item_name) as items
FROM item t1 LEFT JOIN menu t2 ON t1.menu_id = t2.menu_id 
WHERE t2.restaurant_id = ?
group by t2.menu_name"; 
$datamenu = DB::prepare($sqlmenu)->execute([$restaurant_id])->fetchAll();

foreach($datamenu as $rowmenu){ 
        <ul>
                <li><?php echo $rowmenu['menu_name']; ?></li>
                    <?php 
                        $items = $rowmenu['items'] ;
                        $items_array = explode(',',$items);
                        if(is_array($items_array) && count($items_array) > 0 ){
                        ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php
                                    foreach($items_array as $item_name){
                                ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <?php echo $item_name; ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php }?>
        </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @ Abhik Chakraborty.. i also want to display price of every item with the name, can u please suggest there also... i tried manipulating query but getting same price for all items :|

Comment: price is in which table ? item ?

Comment: yups.. the price as item_price

Comment: Yes group by clause will only return the one value for the amount. I made a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86f4c/4, you can concate the item and price with a seperator and then group_concat. SO the items will come as `cat1-10.50,cat2-12.50,cat2-11.50` for one parent menu. Once you do explode with , you have item name and price and if you want can explode it `cat1-10.50` so arr[0] is item name and $arr[1] is price. You can change your code accordingly.

Comment: let me know if this helps !! all you need to concate the item and price together and then group concate in the query. Finally you can do the same thing i.e. explode() and get the items. Now you may need another level of explode on the exploded data to get the item and price seperated.

Comment: Hi @  Abhik Chakraborty  .. apologies to bother u again.. m trying to implode `-` for that array but not able to do same as i want to show Item name and Item Price at different places..

Comment: hmm you mean not within the menu ?

Comment: Within the menu only... but in different column

Comment: can you post your code in https://eval.in/ and give me the URL I will modify that and see if I can help you.

Comment: check this I have added the code https://eval.in/140355 I have added the code, $name_explode[0] is the item name $name_explode[1] will be price, also check the column name in the query I have used as price.

Comment: will check @Abhik Chakraborty ... u r great person who is ready to help anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Without using 2 queries, you could order by the menu Name, then check to see if you've got a new one or not.

```
 $sqlmenu = "SELECT * FROM 
             item t1 LEFT JOIN menu t2 
             ON t1.menu_id = t2.menu_id 
              WHERE  t2.restaurant_id = ? 
              ORDER BY t2.Menu_name"; 
   $datamenu = DB::prepare($sqlmenu)->execute([$restaurant_id])->fetchAll();
   $lastMenu = '';?>
                <ul>
    <?php foreach($datamenu as $rowmenu): ?>
                <?php  if($lastMenu != $rowmenu['menu_name']):
                             if($lastMenu != ''):?>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                           <?php  endif; ?>
                    <li><?php echo $rowmenu['menu_name']; ?>
                        <ul>
                 <?php endif; ?>
                            <li>
                                <?php echo $rowmenu['item_name']; ?>
                            </li>
                 <?php  
                   $lastMenu = $rowmenu['menu_name'];
                endforeach; ?>
                 </ul>
```

I like the other answer better, but I just wanted to post this for clarity since I started telling you what I meant  in comments.

Comment: yeah.. Appreciated Bryan

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly pretty, but I think this (untested) code will do what you what. The principle is that at each iteration of your data, you check whether there is a change in the main menu. This, however, assumes the list to be ordered by main menu.

Another strategy would involve iterating the data and build a multidimensional array.

MySQL only return in two dimensions per query, so you can't really do what you want in SQL alone.

```
<?php /* do the SQL  */ ?>

<ul><!-- start unordered list of main menus -->
<?php 
    $currentmenu = "";
    $first = true;
    foreach($datamenu as $rowmenu) { 
      if ($currentmenu != $rowmenu['menu_id']) { //if new main menu
          if ($!first) {
                echo '</ul>'; //end previous sub menu list
          } else {
                $first = false;
          }
          echo '<li>'.$rowmenu['menu_name'].'</li><ul>'; //start new sub menu list
          $currentmenu = $rowmenu['menu_id']; //remember current menu
      }
?>
      <li>
          <?php echo $rowmenu['item_name']; ?>
      </li>
<?php 
    }
?>
    </ul> <!-- end last unordered list of sub menus -->
</ul> <!-- end unordered list of main menus -->
```